# I want to change the content of a div with JQuery or JavaScript where i click the button and string greater than 70 should appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried lots of methods in java script as well as j query but string greater than 70 does not show up whenever i click the button.You can see my code below:

```
<button id="addtext">Add text</button>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#addtext").click(function(){
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo


 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse";
 $("h2").text(addT);
});
 });
</script>
```

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: you need to share what you have done so far when it comes to helping you with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your question. But if your trying to add a text, you could do it like this:

**Html**

```
<button id="addtext">Add/Remove text</button>
<p id="YourText"></p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#addtext").click(function(){
     $("#YourText").toggle().html("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse");
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZRVJN)